# gcc 8.2.0 build fails on LFS v8.3

Tags: make, gcc, lfs

While building all packages in order every single one of them has succeeded but gcc 8.2.0 build fails.

Below is the build error on executing `make`:

> msgfmt: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you configure exactly as specified in section 6.21? If so, can you provide your configure output and your make output? What is it attempting to build when you get the msgfmt error?

Finally, make sure that you review what you did in chapter 5. msgfmt is part of gettext. If you built gettext improperly, this may be causing your issue also.

Comment: I started all the way from start and the build succeeded this time.